# How do I get the ubuntu OS to recognize my device speakers?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, headphones, speakers

One day I plugged in and plugged out my headphones, and my laptop speakers were no longer being detected by ubuntu. It showed me a dummy output. I played with around with a few solutions and now it shows me sound through the HDMI/Display Port and still no sound through my device's speakers. How do I fix this problem?

I use an HP Pavilion.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have an issue with the jack. Headphone jack has a switch that cuts out the speakers when headphones are plugged in.Maybe dirty or bent or worn . Might try a bit of spray contact cleaner (only a little).

Comment: No there's no issue with the jack... I checked using Windows

Answer (score 0):

May be an alsa misconfiguration?
Sometimes the level bars go down an it seems that there is no sound.
Check this. Open a terminal and write alsamixer, then press enter. Take a look on that yo be sure that the sound levels are ok.